# Align logo on top left of Image in image view

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to place a logo on top left of image inside image view. Image cannot be scaled or no scale type can be assigned. Image should be of its original size. The logo should always be on top left of the image on all screens.

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.imgviewPager);

        List<String> imagesList = new ArrayList<>();
        imagesList.add("http://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503919545889-aef636e10ad4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg");
        imagesList.add("http://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533738699159-d0c68059bb61?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg");
        imagesList.add("http://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500462918059-b1a0cb512f1d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg");
        imagesList.add("http://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516474504835-58236f241ee8?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg");


        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(this,imagesList));

    }
```

**Custom Adapter**

```
class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> imgs;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context,List<String> img) {
        mContext = context;
        imgs = img;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_item, collection, false);
        collection.addView(layout);
        ImageView imageView = layout.findViewById(R.id.img);
        Picasso.get().load(imgs.get(position)).into(imageView);

        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imgs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "";
    }
```

**ImageAdapter item**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|bottom">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Style**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:ignore="NewApi">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Right now the code is written such a way that all the screen sizes are hard coded into the code and logo is adjusted for each screen size. Images sizes are all the same (1080px x 1620px). But this is not scalable approach for the new devices thats coming into the market.

[image]

[image]

Comment: use wrap_content property and set the image in src not as background 
with android:scaleType="fitStart" attribute https://abhiandroid.com/ui/scaletype-imageview-example.html

Comment: Only url image can be loaded. Image cannot be stored in app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use [adjustViewBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) on the main image, and set your logo [alignTop](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout#ALIGN_TOP) of it in a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This looks great. Logo is initially loaded on the bottom of the screen. Only after loading the image, logo takes the correct position.

Comment: Is there any workaround to fix this initial loading error.

Comment: @SalluSalman Hmm.. you could try setting the logo visibility programmatically if that works for you.

Comment: Just replace `layout_alignTop` with `layout_alignParentTop` for logo...

Comment: @makvasic SalluSalman wants the logo to align with the image, not the parent.

Comment: @Aaron oh I see my bad, then there's no way to position logo properly until image is loaded... Maybe try to set `minWith` and `minHeight` for the image...